# How to Get data from a window to another one with Angular and Subject?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, subject

I would like to make a little quizz game with 2 differents views.
One is for the player, answering questions by gambling points on a web server (nodejs).
The other one is for a streamer, observing the game.

I would like to get data from a first browser and display them on another one in my Angular code. Player and Observer are not in the same place. I can't use cookies or local storage so I'm trying to do that via a Subject.

I created a service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {  
    private dataSubject = new Subject<any>();
  
    sendData(data: any) {
      this.dataSubject.next(data);
    }
  
    clearData() {
      this.dataSubject.next();
    }
  
    getData() {
      return this.dataSubject.asObservable();
    }
  
  
}
```

I made 2 components, one for each window.

In the first component, I have a button to send data

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page1',
  templateUrl: '<button (click)="click()">Send data</button>',
  styleUrls: ['./page1.component.css']
})
export class Page1Component implements OnInit{
  
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }

  click(){
    this.sharedService.sendData('test');
  }
}
```

In the second document, I would like to get the 'test' string from the first window to the console

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page2',
  templateUrl: './page2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page2.component.css']
})
export class Page2Component implements OnInit{

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.sharedService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }
}
```

I'm new with Angular. Is someone can give me some advice ? Is this the good way to do or should I do something else ?

Comment: It looks fine for me. Is it working?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "window". So for example you want to be able to send data from one browser-tab to another? Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: Thank you for you anwsers. I updated my initial post to clarify what I would like.

Comment: On startup every browser-instance downloads the entire Angular-app, compiled into javascript (or it fetches the app from the browser-cache). This means your services are **not** shared between browsers (let alone if the browsers are on different laptops). If you want two tabs of the same browser to communicate with each others, you can do it via localstorage. If you want two different browsers to communicate with each others you probably need to send the data via backend.

Comment: That will be 2 differents browsers. I'll do it via backend, I missed a step and didn't released each tab or each every browser got one different instance of the app.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: May I give you another advise? Do you know Signal-R? It's a very helpful library when you want to establish communication between different browsers (clients). A while ago I used Signal-R in an Angular / .Net game-app which provided multiplayer-mode. Microsoft offers Signal-R libraries for different technologies. Alternatively you could look for some other libraries that are based on the webSocket protocol.

Comment: The advantage of the above mentioned libraries: When one browser/client emits an event, you can submit it to the backend and the backend can then inform all the other browsers / clients about this event. This allows all browsers to be always synchronized, so e.g. if player 1 performs an action, player 2 will immediately see it without having to manually refresh his view.

Comment: If your server is using nodejs I suggest using [socket.io](https://socket.io). Basically one client will send a request to the server and the server could broadcast to all watching clients.